# Readability concerns with literal dictionary lookup vs if-else

Tags: python, hash-map, lookup

I'm having concerns about the readability of this piece of code:

```py
    messages_dict = {'error':errors, 'warning':warnings}[severity]
    messages_dict[field_key] = message
```

and I'm to use this instead:

```py
    if severity == 'error':
        messages_dict = errors
    elif severity == 'warning':
        messages_dict = warnings
    else:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect severity value')
    messages_dict[field_key] = message
```

But it looks too verbose for such a simple thing.

I don't care too much if it's more efficient than constructing a dictionary for just two mappings. Readability and maintainability is my biggest concern here (`errors` and `warnings` are method arguments, so I cannot build the lookup dictionary beforehand and reuse it later).

Comment: I don't see the readability concern with the first case.

Comment: I thought that it might puzzle an unaware reader...

Comment: Unaware of what? Dictionaries? They are a core Python data structure - if someone can't read that, they don't know Python. You can't write code that is readable for someone who have no idea.

Comment: I meant unaware of the 'pattern' (using a dict to choose between two options). I've seen complaints in peer reviews about using boolean operators in a similar way (like `x = something or default`, maybe a little bit more complex) because it was _obscure_ :-/

Comment: That's a different situation, as it's relatively unclear what is going on (and is better replaced by the ternary operator). This isn't particularly a pattern, it's just a use of dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention maintainability I think that the consideration can be taken in terms of what next changes may look like. If further changes will take more statements to be executed with the result of one of those specific options, or if more options will be added, I would stick to the dictionary approach.

Looking into the future can certainly be tricky, but you need to also think how much will the code need to be change to assert a specific new need. If you need to add a new level of reporting, would you prefer to add a new `else if` or just a value in a dictionary?

Readability then starts to backfire, since `if ... else` is quite common. What happens when you arrive at 3, 4 or 5 branches?

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly the same, as they behave differently when given an invalid severity. For a fair comparison, the first example code should probably be something like:

```
try:
    messages_dict = {'error':errors, 'warning':warnings}[severity]

except KeyError:
    raise ValueError(f'Incorrect severity value: {severity}.')

messages_dict[field_key] = message
```